# How to mount 7 desktop pc's into a 7u rack?

Tags: mount, desktop-computer, cluster, chassis, rack

I am clustering 7 desktop computers and would like to put them in a rack. I have an 8U rack and 1U will be taken up by the ethernet switch. I will take out the optical drives. I plan on putting each in a 1U chassis like [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/200928089043) or other open ones.

I have three problems:

- Processor Heat Sink
- Hard Drive
- Power Supply

  1. Processor Heat Sink:
     Do I need a heat sink if I put in tons of fans? If yes, could I get a laptop heat sink even though it is a desktop cpu? Any other creative ideas?
  2. Hard Drive:
     There are rack-mountable hard drive holders that can hold 8 hard drives while taking 1U of the rack. Would that work if all hard drives belonged to separate independent computers? I could probably just get long SATA cords to connect to pc. What about power for hard drives? (I would have to keep one computer in its case) Any other creative ideas?
  3. Power Supply:
     The only thing I can think of for this would be to have them hanging out the back of the rack? Any other creative ideas?

I know this is a lot for one question, so if you can answer anything or give any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated. If there are any better way to mount desktops in racks, please mention. I don't have the rack real estate for more than 1U per computer though. By the way, I want to mount the dell optiplex 760 desktop version. If there are any other brackets that I need to buy or rack mounting tips, please share. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want rack-mountable computers, buy rack-mountable computers, with all the right parts. "Desktop" computers are meant to NOT be rack-mounted, so you'll need to source replacement parts that work in a rack. In short 1) Yes, you NEED a heatsink. 2) This would depend entirely on the hardware chosen. 3) Get real 1U chassis with real 1U power supplies.

Comment: Your idea is a disaster waiting to happen

Comment: I have to ask, is this [one of those bitcoin rigs](http://bitcoinexaminer.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Mining-rig-extraordinaire-the-Trenton-BPX6806-mod.jpg)?

Comment: The cases you linked will only work with a motherboard meant to fit in there. There’s only one, and it’s old. Very old. If you want 1U, you need to buy complete machines or barebones.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. These computers were given to me for free so I couldn't pick them out and I am on an extremely tight budget, so I am trying to make this work. Can I get a laptop heatsink for the desktop cpu? or do I need to use the one that came with the computer?

Comment: @Jason No, it is not a bitcoin rig. It is a learning experience of clustering. I saw that we have an old rack laying around, so I thought that I might try to mount it later.

Comment: If you want to try clustering, just use a pile of VM's on a single host, MUCH cheaper. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The point is to create one powerful machine, not overload one computer(if I am understanding you correctly)

Comment: In the comments you just said the point was "a learning experience of clustering". If that's the goal, then VM's will suffice.  If your goal was "I want to hack computers apart and shoe-horn them into someplace they're not intended to fit without spending a dime" then I'd say continue on with your existing plan.  :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I just wanted to cluster them together for a good experience. The rack was just an idea I had later to make it look nicer.

Comment: Clustering *does not* make one powerful machine.  Clustering allows for multiple machines to take a distributed load.  Without the proper software and management, you simply have a bunch of machines.

Comment: @Keltari "The computer clustering approach usually (but not always) connects a number of readily available computing nodes (e.g. personal computers used as servers) via a fast local area network.[3] The activities of the computing nodes are orchestrated by "clustering middleware", a software layer that sits atop the nodes and allows the users to treat the cluster as by and **large one cohesive computing unit**, e.g. via a single system image concept." [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster)

Comment: It’s nice how you quote Wikipedia. But you’re still very far from understanding how HPC works. The “clustering middleware” (e.g. MPI) needs to be tightly(!) integrated into the source code of applications that are expected to distribute their workload. You cannot use normal software for this.

Comment: I wasn't trying to start an argument. As I said earlier, it is a learning experience. I was thinking about using [mpich2](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://curveto.blogspot.com/2008/03/mpich2-under-windows-vista.html&usd=2&usg=ALhdy29Uk3K1472oqSjE1riQ66K-EboaKw). How well do you think that will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chassis you linked won't mount an microATX board.  But let's assume you did find a 1U chassis, *and* it mounted an microATX board, *and* a 3.5" drive, *and* it had an EPS1U power supply.

1. **Processor Heatsink** - You would need to replace the heatsink with a socket 775 1U heatsink, such as [this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA4CP1GG1905).  These heatsinks rely on the small, noisy chassis fans to cool the processor.
2. **Hard Drive** It's not uncommon to find a 1U chassis with mounts for 3.5" hard drives.
3. **Power Supply**  An EPS1U power supply has  an 8-pin connector, which if you're lucky, would plug into the 4-pin connector on your motherboard (the other half of the connector would just hang there).  If it doesn't fit, and since no one seems to sell an adapter for this (the opposite is common), you could cut the plug in half (don't laugh, I've done it before).

There is a lot of things that could potentially go wrong with this.  I wouldn't count on it working, but if it's a hobby project, then have fun!

Comment: Throwing out the money consideration for a second, would [this](http://www.plinkusa.net/web1004m.htm) work for my situation?

Comment: @user2297366 Sure looks like it.  Instead of using a EPS1U power supply, they're using a FlexATX power supply.  I hadn't seen this before, but it's a good thing in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This strikes me as a very bad idea. You might be better off with the following:

Assuming the Dell Optiplex 760 Desktop chassis (H - 15.7", W - 4.5", D - 13.9") :

1. Purchase a standard 19" 24 U rack.
2. Purchase two rack mount shelves.
3. Install the shelves such that you can place (standing up) 4 units on each shelf.
4. Mount the switch.
5. Profit.

If you're actually talking about the Dell Optiplex 760 mini tower chassis then you'll need a standard 19" 42U rack.

Comment: That is what I would like to do, but I am on an extremely tight budget. This is a project with some of school's old computers and an unused rack. This is for the school and I am not supposed to use any of school's money(I could maybe convince to give <$100).

Comment: Something like [http://www.wayfair.com/Middle-Atlantic-WRK-Series-Additional-Rackrail-Kit-10-32-Threaded-WRK-RRXX-L337-K~DF3143.html?refid=GX21919119780-DF3143_1592619&device=c&ptid=25232613060&PiID%5B%5D=1592619&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=DF3143_1592619&gclid=Cj0KEQjw06GfBRCR9tDI4t6n5_MBEiQAFo6kuGZHzG9nxCx0F3F9XGPbGC2bD4w4pbqKGF84f9_iPGgaAuzU8P8HAQ]"this"

Comment: and http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?gclid=Cj0KEQjw06GfBRCR9tDI4t6n5_MBEiQAFo6kuNg1MDeIHmJNeZ4c5kYkbjQPSyXWTSvTMtCKiblXnaUaAsrL8P8HAQ&Item=N82E16816129097&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-Server+Racks+%2f+Cabinets-_-N82E16816129097&ef_id=U767IgAABNdL@nmy:20140811192928:s